Cannot build my app on Expo due to dependency issue with React Native svg charts
I have recently made an app and I am trying to build it for TestFlight.
In my app I started using react-native-svg-charts which uses react-native-svg.
These are the version in my package.json:
"react-native-svg": "^15.3.0",
"react-native-svg-charts": "^5.4.0",
"react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
When I do npx expo start, I can see my app runs and it's alright, when I do eas build --platform iOS then the build fails because:
Running "npm install" in /Users/expo/workingdir/build directory
npm
ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR!
ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm
ERR! While resolving: react-native-svg-charts@5.4.0
npm ERR! Found: react-native-svg@15.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-svg
npm ERR!   react-native-svg@"^15.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native-svg@"> 6.4.1" from react-native-chart-kit@6.12.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-chart-kit
npm ERR!     react-native-chart-kit@"^6.12.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (react-native-gifted-charts)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-svg@"^6.2.1||^7.0.3" from react-native-svg-charts@5.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-svg-charts
npm ERR!   react-native-svg-charts@"^5.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native-svg@7.2.1
npm
ERR! node_modules/react-native-svg
npm ERR!   peer react-native-svg@"^6.2.1||^7.0.3" from react-native-svg-charts@5.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-svg-charts
npm ERR!     react-native-svg-charts@"^5.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/expo/.npm/_logs/2024-06-16T18_10_33_225Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/expo/.npm/_logs/2024-06-16T18_10_33_225Z-debug-0.log
npm install exited with non-zero code: 1

when I do npm install I get:
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-svg-charts@5.4.0
npm ERR! Found: react-native-svg@15.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-svg
npm ERR!   react-native-svg@"^15.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native-svg@"> 6.4.1" from react-native-chart-kit@6.12.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-chart-kit
npm ERR!     react-native-chart-kit@"^6.12.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (react-native-gifted-charts)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-svg@"^6.2.1||^7.0.3" from react-native-svg-charts@5.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-svg-charts
npm ERR!   react-native-svg-charts@"^5.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native-svg@7.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-svg
npm ERR!   peer react-native-svg@"^6.2.1||^7.0.3" from react-native-svg-charts@5.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-svg-charts
npm ERR!     react-native-svg-charts@"^5.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/niloufar/.npm/_logs/2024-06-16T18_14_27_517Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/niloufar/.npm/_logs/2024-06-16T18_14_27_517Z-debug-0.log

so there are some dependency issues, if I do this:
npm uninstall react-native-svg
npm i react-native-svg@7.0.3
then I can do npm install, but when I do npx expo start, then I get :
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if: * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project. * A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes 

I am running out of ideas, no matter what I do I get some error. Do I need to not use the react-native-svg-charts?

You have resolved the dependency conflict correctly, however something else is preventing app from running and causing "Invariant Violation".
I would advice clearing metro cache, reinstalling dependencies, restarting metro and running the app again, while carefully checking metro logs and device logs. You should see an error happening before the Invariant Violation.
If you confirm that the error is caused by react-native-svg@7.0.3, you could try using a newer version: react-native-svg@^7.0.3 or v6: react-native-svg@^6.2.1

I resolved this issue by forking the react-native-svg-charts repository. I updated the version number in the package.json file to match the version used in my app.
After making these changes, I installed the modified library into my project, which successfully fixed the problem.
